# Show that volume integral of div of a cross product is zero

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

I had to show that
$$\iiint_{R^3}  Y\cdot(\nabla\times X)dV=\iiint_{R^3} X\cdot (\nabla \times Y)dV$$
By using the identity as indicated by the excercise
$$Y\cdot(\nabla\times X)-X\cdot (\nabla \times Y)=\nabla\cdot(X\times Y)$$
I get

$$\iiint_{R^3} \nabla\cdot(X\times Y)\ dV =0$$
Does anyone know how can I prove that? Maybe you can use the divergence theorem and turn it into surface integral but I have been trying with no success. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Is the integral taken over an arbitrary surface?

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ arbitrary $C^1$ vectors?  If not, what properties do they have?

Comment: In the exercise it says that X,Y are smooth vector fields on R^3 @Mark

Comment: The integration is taken over R^3 ,,I don't know if it means an arbitrary volume or all space but I think it's more likely it means an arbitrary volume. @tilper

Comment: Do they approach $0$ as $|\vec r|\to \infty$?

Comment: It doesn't say they do..Do you think that  $R^3$ means an arbitrary volume or all space? Do you think I can prove it if I use divergenve theorem and turn it into $\iint_S (X\times Y)\cdot n dS$ @MarkViola

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^3$ denotes all of space.  Use of the Divergence theorem won't help unless the product of the fields approaches $0$ faster than $1/r^2$.